# why iperf perfomance on windows is bad compared to iperf on linux?

Tags: tcp, device-driver, android-wifi, ethernet, data-link-layer

i am tring to measure TCP throughput between my android device and access point. 
setup:-

```
Android device<------>AP<---connected wired(10Gbps ethernet)----->windows/linux laptop
```

iperf is giving a 5-8 Mbps high tput when i used linux laptop at other end.

iperf version used-2.0.5 on windows.
                   2.0.4 on linux.

Anyone have any idea about this behaviour..?